# Making a future prediction with trained Tensorflow model (LSTM-RNN)

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am having an issue with how to tell my **`RNN-LSTM model`** to generate future values. I think that I need to append values to "inputs" so that `X_test` extends beyond my test data set and into the future, but how should I go about that, or what should those values be? Go easy on me here, just getting into python/machine learning.

`X_test.shape = (193, 60, 5)` by the end of this code, by the way, containing "***Open, High, Low, Close, Volume***" values.

```
past_60_days = data_training.tail(60)

df = past_60_days.append(data_test, ignore_index = True)
df = df.drop(['Date', 'Adj Close'], axis = 1)

inputs = scaler.transform(df)

X_test = []
y_test = []

for i in range(60, inputs.shape[0]):
  X_test.append(inputs[i-60:i])
  y_test.append(inputs[i, 0])

X_test, y_test = np.array(X_test), np.array(y_test)

y_pred = regressior.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `Time Series Analysis` and yes, Forecasting the Future Predictions can be done using `LSTM` (RNN).

For example, you want to Forecast Next Days Value, considering past 60 days Data, important part of code would be

```
def multivariate_data(dataset, target, start_index, end_index, history_size,
                      target_size):
  data = []
  labels = []

  start_index = start_index + history_size
  if end_index is None:
    end_index = len(dataset) - target_size

  for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = range(i-history_size, i)
    data.append(dataset[indices])

    labels.append(target[i:i+target_size])

  return np.array(data), np.array(labels)

past_history = 60
future_target = 1

x_train, y_train = multivariate_data(dataset, dataset[:, 0], 0,
                                                   training_data_len, past_history,
                                                   future_target)
x_val_single, y_val_single = multivariate_data(dataset, dataset[:, 0],
                                               training_data_len, None, past_history,
                                               future_target)
```

Please refer this [Comprehensive Tensorflow Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#part_2_forecast_a_multivariate_time_series) which has the complete code for `Multi-Variate Data` (Multiple Columns like `Open, Close, High, Low, etc..`), which Predicts a `Single Step` and `Multiple Steps`.

If you face any error while implementing it, please reach out and I will be Happy to help you.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!